# section within table, can't set listener (keyup and blur) to div that are in td

Tags: jquery, listener

I have a table in a section and i can't set keyup and blur listener, but i can only set click listener.

```
$('.divTesto').bind("keyup", function(){
     console.log("Key up");
 });

 $('#0_0').bind("blur", function(){
     console.log("Blur");
 });
```

Why?! 
I make jsfiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/juN4j/

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get div onblur event to execute a javascript function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847986/how-to-get-div-onblur-event-to-execute-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0):

`blur` events do not occur on a `div` element, even when it is contenteditable unfortunately.

You can only have that event on `input` | `a` | `button` | `select` | etc etc