# Javascript : Onblur on a group of Input

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to add onblur event on a container of 2 input below  ?

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <input id="firstName" type="text" />
   </td>

   <td>
     <input id="lastName" type="text" />
   </td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might not be able to have an onblur for a div if you happen to put that as a container for your inputs grouped together.

this might help

[How to get div onblur event to execute a javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847986/how-to-get-div-onblur-event-to-execute-a-javascript-function)